# Formatting currencies to display in Switzerland for fr-CH locale

Tags: javascript, internationalization, locale

We are seeing different formatting styles for currencies and numbers in Switzerland fr language.
When we format a number it uses commas for separators, but when we pass a style as a currency it uses period for that. Is this the expected behavior

```
var num = 16.15;
console.log("FR CH: " + 
        new Intl.NumberFormat("fr-CH").format(num ));
console.log("FR CH Curr: " + 
        new Intl.NumberFormat("fr-CH", {style: "currency", currency: "EUR"}).format(num ));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h4xm6qpb/2/

Answer (score 1):

Based on this https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/fr-CH/index.html
This seems to be the correct approach. The decimal separator and the monitory decimal separators are different